# Remove highlighting from bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have example with table [here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/egjxgv?editors=1010)

I would like to remove highlighting from the row on the row click.

When I hover on the row, background is greyed. I would like to be able to remove greyed background on the row click, so that row stays without setted background.

Is this possible?

I've already made function which selects the cell and row being clicked:

```
var test = function(element){
    var tdCaller = $(element);
    var parentRow = tdCaller.parent();
    var parentBody = parentRow.parent();
}
```

But I don't know how to remove highlighting from that row on click?

Comment: So you still want hover states, you just want rows that have been clicked to not have the hover state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to minimize changes to your code:

[The link is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNLXWq).

Html (added class on tr):

```
<table id="tblBAENWC" class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed col-sm-12">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="mytr">
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">First name</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="mytr">
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">First name</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="mytr">
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">First name</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="mytr">
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="test(this);">First name</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Javascript (look after comment "my add"):

```
var test = function(element) {

    var tdCaller = $(element);
    var parentRow = tdCaller.parent();
    var parentBody = parentRow.parent();

    // my add
    $('tr.mytr.clicked').removeClass('clicked')
    parentRow.addClass('clicked');
  }
```

CSS (look after comment "my add"):

```
.MarkSelectedRow {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

/* my add */
.table-hover tbody tr.mytr.clicked {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set `background:none` to clicked row.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.table-hover tbody tr').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'none'); // Whatever color you want
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css>
<table id="tblBAENWC" class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed col-sm-12">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">First name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">First name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">First name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">1</td>
      <td style="cursor:pointer;">First name</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will help.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.table-hover tr').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');
  });
});
```

```css
/* When table row hover */

.table-hover tr:hover td{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  color: #ffffff;
}
/* After clicked row if user hover again */
.table-hover tr.no-hover:hover td{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table Head 1</th>
      <th>Table Head 2</th>
      <th>Table Head 3</th>
      <th>Table Head 4</th>
      <th>Table Head 5</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell content 1</td>
      <td>Table cell content 2</td>
      <td>Table cell content 3</td>
      <td>Table cell content 4</td>
      <td>Table cell content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell content 1</td>
      <td>Table cell content 2</td>
      <td>Table cell content 3</td>
      <td>Table cell content 4</td>
      <td>Table cell content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell content 1</td>
      <td>Table cell content 2</td>
      <td>Table cell content 3</td>
      <td>Table cell content 4</td>
      <td>Table cell content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell content 1</td>
      <td>Table cell content 2</td>
      <td>Table cell content 3</td>
      <td>Table cell content 4</td>
      <td>Table cell content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell content 1</td>
      <td>Table cell content 2</td>
      <td>Table cell content 3</td>
      <td>Table cell content 4</td>
      <td>Table cell content 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css.
Give this code in css file

```
tr:hover td {background:#fff;}
```

You dont need jquery to change background color on hover.It can be done with CSS

If you want the color to be white on clicking the row,give the below code in JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr').click(function () {
            //Check to see if background color is set or if it's set to white.
                      $(this).css('background', 'white');


      });
});
```

Comment: no, OP said only when the row is clicked. This will apply all the time.

Comment: @ADyson but currently theres no color on click

Comment: yes...but this property will apply _before_ the click as well. OP only wants to remove the hover background colour after the row has been clicked on.